# Have global variable filled in by remote machine when connecting through ssh

Tags: bash, variables, ssh, solaris

I'm having trouble to fill in a variable when connecting to a remote machine through ssh.

I'm trying to execute the following statement in a bash script:

ssh user@host '$INSTALL_DIR/script/replaceAll.sh'" $orig_val $new_val";

$INSTALL_DIR is a global variable on both machines with a different value on each, while $orig_val and $new_val are variables calculated in the script itself. I'm using SunOS 5.10

The problem is that $INSTALL_DIR uses the local value, while it should be using the remote value. Can you tell me what i'm doing wrong here?

Answer (score 2):

Escape the dollar sign:

```
ssh user@host '\$INSTALL_DIR/script/replaceAll.sh'" $orig_val $new_val"
```

Comment: When i do that, the variable isn't resolved on the target machine as well. It gives the following error: 
ksh: $INSTALL_DIR/script/replaceAll.sh: not found

Comment: By the way, i've managed to use an alternative suggested here yesterday, but which was somehow removed by today. By sourcing the profile before running the command, $INSTALL_DIR was filled in correctly using the value on the remote machine: ssh $user@host '. ~/.profile 2>/dev/null; #command here';

Answer (score 0):

your shell's evaluating the variable before passing it to ssh, you need to force the shell to treat the arguments as pure text